# Getting console.log output from Firefox with Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, logging, selenium

I'm trying to get a web page's `console.log` output from Firefox via the python Selenium API bindings.  Based on the [code for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings), and some [advice from the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DeveloperTips#Getting_output_from_the_error_console_to_a_file), I tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities   
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('webdriver.log.file', '/tmp/firefox_console')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d,firefox_profile=fp)
driver.set_window_size(1280,1024)
driver.get('http://foo.com')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print entry
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

But, for even a simple example page that calls `console.log("foo")`, I don't see `"foo"` either in the log entries returned via the API or in the `/tmp/firefox_console` file.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a Selenium limitation?

Comment: This is for people coming now to check answers. driver.get_log('browser') is not working for firefox as of this date. There is an open issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1161

Comment: The issue mentioned above was closed in favor of a new one: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/284 - still unfixed. But Firefox 65+ introduced a "devtools.console.stdout.content" preference, which dumps the console.log output to stdout.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct when it comes to the `get_log` function, just add a `print` statement at the end like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d)
# load some site
driver.get('http://foo.com')
# print messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry

print

driver.quit()
```

In fact:

```
print len(driver.get_log('browser'))
```

returns `53` in my example with this as a sample entry in the list:

```
{u'timestamp': 1407591650751, u'message': u"Expected ':' but found '}'.  Declaration dropped.", u'level': u'WARNING'}
```

Seems like a bad char problem. As for why there is no output in the `/tmp/firefox_console` file, I have no clue, the logger seems to throw some webdriver debug info but no `console.log` output.

**EDIT**: Apparently the above code does not return data from `console.log`. It's not a Selenium bug as far as I can tell but a problem with Firefox. I managed to get around it by installing the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) along with [ConsoleExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-extension-consoleexport-send-console-logs-to-the-server/) plugin for Firebug, then point it to some logging server. See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681072/selenium-how-to-turn-on-firebug-with-console-script-and-net) for details on how to enable Firebug programmatically from Selenium.

See this gist for more details: https://gist.github.com/CGenie/fc63536a8467ae6ef945

Comment: I wasn't saying that I get no log output from the driver, just that I'm not getting the `console.log` output.  Are you seeing `console.log` output in the driver log entries?

Comment: It seems that uncatched exceptions and syntax errors are logged as SEVERE. This looks promising for catching JS errors with automated tests.

Answer (score 2):

There have been changes in implementation. I was also using:

```
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
```

but now I am using Python3.8, Selenium 3.4 and it is not working/implemented anymore.
See another Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196421/not-able-to-get-console-logs-on-firefox-webdriver) discussing it.

Otherwise you get the error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: loggingPrefs is not the name of a known capability or extension capability`