# Not able to get console logs on firefox webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using  Firefox version 53. Geckodriver version 0.16, selenium version 3.4. I want totake console logs of webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d)
driver.set_window_size(1280,1024)
driver.get('http://google.com')
try:
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print entry
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Console output

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/GS-0758/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py
Starting selenium session 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GS-0758/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 153, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 189, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 253, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: loggingPrefs was not a the name of a known capability or a valid extension capability
```

Answer (score 3):

It's known issue, you can check it here

> geckodriver is an implementation of W3C WebDriver which doesn’t
>   specify a log interface at the moment, so this is expected behaviour.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/330